# Is there any standard notation for turing machines outcomes?

Tags: turing-machines

On 2 symbols 1-state turning machine, there are 64 posible machines taking into account their transition tables.
One of this machines could be:
$$A0:0LA$$
$$A1:0RH$$

(meaning:
in state A, reading a 0, write 0, goes left and transition to A,
in state A, reading a 1, write 0, goes right and halt.)

Another one could be:
$$A0:1RA$$
$$A1:0RA$$

Another one:
$$A0:1LH$$
$$A1:0RA$$

Assuming we start with a blank tape, only the last one halts. The first just keep going left, and the second just goes right writing 1's.

On 2 symbols 1-state machines, there are 64 posible machines (if we consider transition tables as they source code).
But if we consider their behaviour there are only 8 possible outcomes.

1. Going Left: $(0L)*$
2. Going Right: $(0R)*$
3. Going Left writing 1's: $(1L)*$
4. Going Right writing 1's: $(1R)*$
5. Go left and halt: $0LH$
6. Write 1,go left and halt: $1LH$
7. Go right and halt: $RH$
8. Write 1, go right and halt: $1RH$

(Only the last 4, halt)

For 2 symbols n-state machines:

- The formula for calculating how many machines in terms of transition tables are $(2*2*2*(n+1))^n$? My rational: 2 read symbols, 2 write symbols, 2 directions, (n+1) next states to be defined (independently) in n (running) states
- Is there some kind of standard notation for outcomes?
- Is there a formula for calculating outcomes?

For 2 symbols 2-state machines:

- There are 1296 machines (if my previous formula is ok), but how many outcomes?
- It is known how many of this 1296 halts?